# Prevent external files in src of iframe from being cached (with CloudFlare)

Tags: caching, iframe, browser-cache, cloudflare, html-head

I am trying to make a playground like plunker. I just noticed a very odd behavior on production (with `active mode` in Cloudflare), whereas it works well in `localhost`.

By `iframe`, the playground previews `index_internal.html` which may contain links to other files (eg, `.html`, `.js`, `.css`). `iframe` is able to interpret external links such as `<script src="script.js"></script>`.

So each time a user modifies their file (eg, `script.js`) on the editor, my program saves the new file into a temporary folder on the server, then refresh the iframe by `iframe.src = iframe.src`, it works well on `localhost`.

However, I realized that, in production, the browser always keeps loading the **initial** `script.js`, even though users modify it in the editor and a new version is written in the folder in the server. For example, what I see in `Dev Tools ==> Network` is always the initial version of `script.js`, whereas I can check the new version of `script.js` saved in the server by `less` on the left hand.

Does anyone know why it is like this? And how to fix it?

[image]

**Edit 1:**

I tried the following, which did not work with `script.js`:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
iframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
iframe.contentDocument.location.reload(true);
iframe.contentWindow.location.href = iframe.contentWindow.location.href
iframe.contentWindow.src = iframe.contentWindow.src
iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(iframe.contentWindow.location.href)
```

I tried to add a version, it worked with `index_internal.html`, but did not reload `script.js`:

```
var newSrc = iframe.src.split('?')[0] 
iframe.src = newSrc + "?uid=" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
```

If I turn Cloudflare to `development mode`, `script.js` is reloaded, but I do want to keep Cloudflare in `active mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.

We can create a custom rule for caching in CloudFlare:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-#cache

For example, I could set `Bypass` as `Cache Level` for the folder `www.mysite.com/tmp/*`.